# Retrieve the number of a tag after a td tag

Tags: php, dom, tags

in php i want to retrieve the number of A tag that are after a TD tag and before the next TD tag in a php file .. here s an example

```
<td>Title 1</td>
<div></div>
<a> 1</a>
<a>2</a>
<td> title 2</td>
<a>1</a>
<div></div>
```

For the TD Title 1 = 2 a tag
For the TD Title 2 = 1 a tag

i tried everything.. but i have no more solutions.
It needs to be done in php (with DOM maybe :)
Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you want tot get what is between the anchor `<a>` tags, or the `<td>`

Comment: @hek2mgl: because i have to do a script that take links (a tag.. its already done) but the category of the links too (the TD) like a menu.

Comment: @PHP Noob : No just the number of tags (count)

Comment: Check my answer below, I have explained it, it is probably what you wanted, but I still did not undestand it

Comment: Any chance you want to give us the bigger picture? There may be a better way of doing what you're doing rather than just fixing this little bit.

Comment: And can you show how you want this data returned? e.g. `{"Title 1": 2, "Title 2": 1}`

Comment: Also your table HTML is bad; Those anchors would appear below the table.

Comment: That file was not my creation at all -.-

Comment: array[0]=>{array[0] = "Title1", array[1] = "2" }...

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '<td>Title 1</td> <div></div><a> 1</a><a>2</a><td> title 2</td><a>1</a><div></div>';
```

Now, if you want to get the number `1` from `<td>Title 1</td>`

```
<?php 
function get_between($text, "<td>", </td>) 
{ 
  $substr = substr($input, strlen($start)+strpos($input, $start), (strlen($input) - strpos($input, $end))*(-1)); 
  return $substr; 
} 

//Example: 

$foo = get_between($text,"<td>", </td>);
echo (int)$foo;
//will output "1"
?>
```

Comment: I dont want to get the number 1 of Title 1. I want to have the number of <a> tag that are under the <td> tag and before the next <td> tag

Comment: Right, Hulk means the amount of a tags. Probably preg_match_all will do.

Comment: @Hulk well, why not just count the number of `<a>` that are inside `<td>` tags? Will that work for you?

Comment: Thing is @Hulk how are we  to return this data? What arguments are given? The data as it stands produces two results. How are these to be formatted?

Comment: No, the <a> tag are not inside <td>'s

Answer (score 0):

You can use any php data scrapping library or class for finding number of tags in your pages.

try

http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/
or
http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php